# Replace a Stateful EJB by a CDI bean to implement a long conversation without a long transaction

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, transactions

In Jakarta EE 10, I would like to replace a Stateful EJB by a CDI bean (with methods annotated by `@Transactional`) to implement a long conversation without a long transaction (for example to manage a shopping cart). How would you recommend doing it?